# Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema. unknown property 'publicPath'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux, webpack-cli

I am using webpack: 5.71.0
webpack-cli: 4.9.2
webpack-dev-server 4.8.1

in my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: { presets: ["@babel/env"] }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: { extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'] },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: './bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        static: path.join(__dirname, 'public/'),
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/dist/',
        port: 3000,
        hot: "only"
    },
    plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
};
```

I got the following error
[webpack-cli] Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.

- options has an unknown property 'publicPath'. These properties are valid:
  object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, setupMiddlewares?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }

what is the new alternative to publicPath?

Comment: I would highly recommend not using vanilla webpack in favour of better tools like vite, next, astro, or even CRA. While it is an opinion you're not asking for, it simplifies most of the problems you encounter (including this one) - and doesn't require you to manually add style-loader and babel-loader.

Answer (score 19):

Looks like your webpack config was written using v3 of webpack-dev-server. The schema has changed for v4 as per [webpack-dev-server v4 migration guide](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/migration-v4.md)

So your devServer block should place publicPath within the devMiddleware section, i.e.:

```
devServer: {
  static: path.join(__dirname, 'public/'),
  devMiddleware: {
    publicPath: '/dist/'
  },
  port: 3000,
  hot: "only"
},
```

Comment: how about key and cert ? ```    // key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/example.com+5-key.pem'),
    // cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/example.com+5.pem'),```

Comment: How do I get v3?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need to set `publicPath` in the `devServer` configuration at all; it's probably read from `output.publicPath`.

Try to just get rid of it and see if things still work. (They should.)

Comment: yes it run but it gives me this error

Comment: I mean, remove `publicPath` from under `devServer`.

Comment: I edited above comment but it didn't change. I removed publicPath and it compiled successfully but didn't show anything on HTTP://localhost:3000

Comment: If your publicPath is dist, then you'll need `http://localhost:3000/dist/`, of course...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
const path = require('path')
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
require('babel-register')

module.exports = {
    entry: ['@babel/polyfill', './src/app.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new htmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html'
        })
    ],
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
        devServer: {
        static: {
          directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/'),
        },
        devMiddleware: {
            publicPath: '/dist/'
        },
        port: 3000,
        hot: "only"
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Minimum compatible webpack-cli version is 5.0.0